# how to markup a quotation?

Tags: org-mode

How do I specify a quote in org-mode so that it is rendered nicely in github? In markdown it is rendered like so:

> Two things are infinite: the universe and human stupidity; and I'm not sure about the universe.

- *albert enstein*

thanks in advance.

Answer (score 62, accepted):

When quoting a passage from another document, it is customary to format this as a paragraph that is indented on both the left and the right margin. You can include quotations in Org mode documents like this:

```
 #+BEGIN_QUOTE
 Everything should be made as simple as possible,
 but not any simpler -- Albert Einstein
 #+END_QUOTE
```

This information in available in the [org manual](http://orgmode.org/manual/Paragraphs.html)

When you convert your file to html then your text will be as shown below

[image]

Comment: You can insert `#+BEGIN_QUOTE` and `#+END_QUOTE` lines quickly by typing `<q` and then pressing TAB.

Comment: Is there a way to actually add formatting options to the quote in orgmode? E.g. `#+BEGIN_QUOTE -gray_background -blue_margin ...`? Just a silly example, but I'd like to get nice formatting like the OP's.

Comment: Newer versions of Org-mode do not have `<q TAB`, but rather `C-c C-, q` (and its ilk).

Comment: @FernandoBasso you can still have `<q TAB`  shortcut - you need to enable the `org-tempo` sub-module to have these structure template shorthands https://orgmode.org/manual/Structure-Templates.html

Comment: (Thank you @FernandoBasso, I noticed that `<q` had stopped working and was bereft!)

Comment: Just to be clear, there is actually no alternative, such as prefixing each line with a "> "? The objective here is an economy of lines, to see more of the document in the editor. (Yes, I know, this comment should be a separate question.)

Answer (score 14):

If you want to get nice formatting, you can customize the CSS of `blockquote` element.

Why `blockquote` element? If you use browser's inspect function to inspect the quote block, you can find its style is controlled by `blockquote` element.

Below is an example of StackExchange like quote block, you can find the configuration by using inspect function.

```
#+BEGIN_EXPORT html
<style>
blockquote {
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    padding: 10px;
    background-color: #FFF8DC;
    border-left: 2px solid #ffeb8e;
    border-left-color: rgb(255, 228, 102);
    display: block;
    margin-block-start: 1em;
    margin-block-end: 1em;
    margin-inline-start: 40px;
    margin-inline-end: 40px;
}
</style>
#+END_EXPORT

#+BEGIN_QUOTE
Everything should be made as simple as possible,

but not any simpler -- Albert Einstein
#+END_QUOTE
```

It renders like

[image]

In addition to writing css yourself, you can use [alhassy/org-special-block-extras](https://github.com/alhassy/org-special-block-extras) which offers a number of new custom blocks and link types.

Comment: should `#+BEGIN_EXPORT html... ` added top of the file?

Comment: @alper I think any place in the file is ok.