# How can I change color of quoted text in org mode?

Tags: org-mode, quote

When I use `#+BEGIN_QUOTE`.. `#+END_QUOTE` text in between always shown as white.

Example output:
[image]
Related: [how to markup a quotation?](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/27601/how-to-markup-a-quotation)

Is it possible to change color of the quoted text such as to dimmer color?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you want an ad hoc or a permanent change?

If permanent you can change `org-quote`'s face attributes in your init.

See [org-quote](https://doc.endlessparentheses.com/Face/org-quote.html) and [Face-Attributes](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Face-Attributes.html).

Comment: I want permanent change. I have changed org-quote but it did not affect the coloring :-(

Comment: Which theme are you using?

Comment: What does `C-h o org-quote` tell you? Did you activate `org-fontify-quote-and-verse-blocks`?

Comment: it says: `("#+begin_quote" nil '> n p n "#+end_quote" >)`

Comment: looks like `org-fontify-quote-and-verse-blocks` is not activated its nil

Comment: I was using dracula theme: https://github.com/dracula/emacs

Comment: Glad you managed to make it work. I was asking about the theme because some themes like Modus have specific variables to change color faces.